# Jquery validation not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I am trying to do required validation in a asp.net page. 
I have multiple controls that will be hidden and displayed. 
Controls like `checkboxlist`,`dropdownlist`,`multiselectedlistbox`. 
I am using a css class called required attaching to all these controls to check the validation.

I am trying to check if each control has value or not but my code is checking each options with in each controls.

I am really not finding a way not a jquery expert just a novice...

Here is my code any ideas anyone please....

```
                    $("input[type='submit']").click(function () {

                  if ($(this).val() != 'Back') {

                      var names = [];
                      var info=" ";
                     $('.required input').each(function () {
                 var control = $(this);
                 if (control.is(':enabled')) {
                      names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
                 }
             });
             $('.required option').each(function () {
                 var control = $(this);
                 if (control.is(':enabled')) {
                    names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
                 }
             });  
                        for (name in names) {
                          var radio_buttons = $("input[name='" + name + "']");
                          if ((radio_buttons.filter(':checked').length == 0) ||(radio_buttons.filter(':selected').length == 0)) {
                              info += radio_buttons.closest("table").find('label').html()+"</br>";
                          }

                      }
                  if (info != " ") {
                      $("#validation_dialog p").html(info);
                      $("#validation_dialog").dialog({
                          title: "Validation Error!",
                          modal: true,
                          resizable: false,
                          buttons: {
                              Close: function () {
                                  $(this).dialog('close');
                              }
                          }
                      });
                      return false;
                  }
                  }
              });
```

here is a fiddle for it...

http://jsfiddle.net/bDmgk/35/

Comment: You could try using jQuery validation plugin.  http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: I agree with Rick S, use JQuery more. I hate ASP.NET controls, it creates DOM that's hard to read.

Comment: this is a part of sharepoint visual webpart, how do i get the validate method. i tried adding that method but it says undefined method. since it is a sharepoint visual webpart i have no other options that using .Net...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
$(".required input[type='radio']:checked").each(function(){

});
```

instead of :

```
$(".required option").each(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I made some changes to your fiddle basically I checked for the inputs inside each column like this and then I added them to your names array.

Using

```
$('table.required:eq(0) input:checked')
```

I you can got all the inputs that are checked on the first column if the lenght of the array returned is 0 then no input is checked, i't the same procedure for the other ones.

An yes those input names are weird.

Check this fiddle

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/bDmgk/36/)

Comment: Hi Eduardo thanks alot it seems working exactly how i thought. but i have a question. You this is a dynamic page and there is no specific order or no idea of the controls that will be enabled or disabled. This is a question driven page where different controls will be enabled and disabled depending upon the answer.I have to validate the controls and problem is i don't know which will be enabled or disabled. It is dynamically generated.I hope your solution works for any controls. I was targeting three types of controls..listbox,checkboxlist,radiobuttonlist..just wondering..

Comment: As i'm searching for the first table of elements and then the second and then the third i hope this will work with other dinamically generated questions, maybe once when you saw another example you will need to search for the first div of questions and get the label for that div.

Comment: Maybe once looking at the way the dynamic page is generated you can find out a pattern to work with the validation

Comment: Hey Edward, as i started implementing this it is not working the way i was planning. It should check the controls and validate only if it is enabled. right now it is validating all the controls even if it is not enabled.

Comment: On the if add $('table.required:eq(0) input:checked:enabled') or first check if the table has at least 1 enabled input $('table.required:eq(0) input:enabled') > 0

Comment: Hi did the answer helped you?

Comment: i don't know what to say. you know the way you are checking is kind a static. i have 32 controls in the page which are hidden and will be displayed depending on the value of each controls and at one time i might have max 6 controls or more  and i will never have any idea of the order of the controls. now you are checking first two rows radiobuttons but it may be check-box list or listbox. this is not working me for me i appreciate your help

Comment: If they are separated by divs or by tables like in the fiddle you can look first inside on the first element for Checkboxes, raddiobuttons or select elements depending on which one of those you find fire the desired behavior, that's an idea hope it helps you